# Insert into a large table in psycopg using a dictionary

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a VERY large table (>200 columns) in a database, which I'm accessing through psycopg2. I have the rows I want to insert as dictionaries, column name as key and value as value. Using psycopg2, I want to insert the row into the table.

Because of the prohibitively huge number of columns of the table in question, I would rather not write out an insert statement manually. How do I insert the dictionary efficiently and neatly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the test table:

```
create table testins (foo int, bar int, baz int)
```

You can compose a sql statement this way:

```
d = dict(foo=10,bar=20,baz=30)

cur.execute(
    "insert into testins (%s) values (%s)" 
        % (','.join(d), ','.join('%%(%s)s' % k for k in d)),
    d)
```

Comment: Well I'll be, this worked like a charm! I thought there'd be a cleaner way, but this works well enough for now. +1