# Is it safe to use Python % string operator to compose a Psycopg SQL query as long as values are passed separately to cursor.execute()

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2, parameterized

There is plenty of material, most notably the ["Passing parameters to SQL queries" guide on psycopg.org](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/params.html), covering the security problems with using Python's + or % string operators to merge values into a Psycopg2 SQL query.

What I've found unclear is whether or not it is safe to use % to insert the ***field names*** in to the query prior to running cursor.execute(query, values) **with the values dictionary properly passed in as the second argument**. My original need was to dynamically compose queries from variable length dictionaries of field/value pairs.

Following [a different question/answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611288/insert-into-a-large-table-in-psycopg-using-a-dictionary) and other resources, I have my program working as expected with **trusted** input. This example code demonstrates what I'm doing, but I want to understand why the Python % operator is or is not safe in this context. Put another way, could a SQL injection attack be carried out by modifying only the two dictionaries (keys or values)?

```py
from psycopg2 import sql

values = {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
    "field3": "value3",
}

conditions = {
    "field4": "value4",
    "field5": "value5",
}

select_fields = [
    "field1",
    "field3",
]

# INSERT a record using fields/values from the values dictionary
insert_query = sql.SQL(
    r"INSERT INTO tablename (%s) VALUES (%s)"
    % (
        ",".join(values),
        ",".join(r"%%(%s)s" % key for key in values)
    )
)
# equivalent to:
insert_query = sql.SQL(
    r"INSERT INTO tablename (field1,field2,field3) VALUES (%(field1)s,%(field2)s,%(field3)s)"
)


# DELETE all records that match on ALL field/value pairs in the conditions dictionary
delete_query = sql.SQL(
    r"DELETE FROM tablename WHERE (%s) = (%s)"
    % (
        ",".join(conditions),
        ",".join(r"%%(%s)s" % key for key in conditions),
    )
)
# equivalent to:
delete_query = sql.SQL(
    r"DELETE FROM tablename WHERE (field4,field5) = (%(field4)s,%(field5)s)"
)


# SELECT all records that match on ALL field/value pairs in the conditions dictionary
select_query = sql.SQL(
    r"SELECT %s FROM tablename WHERE (%s) = (%s)"
    % (
        ",".join(select_fields),
        ",".join(conditions),
        ",".join(r"%%(%s)s" % key for key in conditions),
    )
)
# equivalent to:
select_query = sql.SQL(
    r"SELECT field1,field3 FROM tablename WHERE (field4,field5) = (%(field4)s,%(field5)s)")

# cursor.execute(a_query, values) # would come next, but that's beyond the scope of my question
```

I spun up a test database and tried injecting SQL into the keys and values of the two dictionaries. I had the query object looking like a ready-to-go injection attack, but Psycopg kept raising errors when I later passed that query and the values to cursor.execute()

If anyone has recommendations on how this could be better accomplished, I'd be very interested in hearing them as well.

Comment: `whether or not it is safe to use % to insert the *field names*` This is called SQL injection. You inject a piece of SQL, the field name, into the rest of your query. If that piece of SQL doesn't match your expectations, a lot of things can go wrong. SQL Injection was discovered in the late '90s last century. I would not write code nowadays that makes the same mistakes again...

Comment: [psycopg2 Passing parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries): *Warning Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.* Following the instructions at the link for proper parameter passing. It so easy to do it safely, just get in that habit.

Comment: It is safe, IF you are in complete control of all the strings being inserted into the query.  In this specific example you're using a hardcoded dictionary, so it is safe.  Those strings will always be exactly what you expected.  **BUT** if the strings themselves actually come from somewhere else (like user input, or an environment variable, or they are the results of some other database query), then no it is not safe.

Comment: If the dictionaries can be filled with arbitrary **keys** from a source you don't control, then it is *definitely not safe* to construct an SQL query from them. The **values** may be okay, assuming you always parameterise them properly (which your current code example seems to do).

Comment: I fixed one issue in the code example, I had reused the "values" dict for select_query, but it should have been a separate select_fields list of strings.

I have been trying to demonstrate it being unsafe by intentionally manipulating the input dictionaries. So far, I haven't been able to. What modification to the input strings would allow an additional SQL command (outside of the composed ones) to be executed?

Comment: Don't do this.  Just don't.  It's a bad habit and it's dangerous.  Even if this particular case is "safe", someone else might see your code and modify it in an unsafe manner.   There's an easy way to safely pass parameters to SQL code.  There's no reason to use any other method.

Comment: @CurtisEveringham For example, if the `"field4"` key of `conditions` was replaced by `"1); --"`, it would result in `DELETE FROM tablename WHERE (1); --,field5) = (%(1); --)s,%(field5)s)`. Note that everything after the first `;` is a comment, so it doesn't matter what garbage appears there. I haven't tested this specific example with psycopg2, so maybe it's clever enough to spot this relatively crude example. But even if it is: do you ***really*** want to bet that it will spot every other possible attack like this?